# Unlist dictionaries from a list

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, dictionary

I have a very large list, so i will use the below as a reproducible example. I would like to unlist the following so i can use the keys of the dictionaries as columns to a dataframe.

```
[{'message':'Today is a sunny day.','comments_count':'45','id': 
'1401305690071546_11252160039985938','created_time': '2020-02-29T13:43:46+0000'},
{'message':'Today is a cloudy day.','comments_count':'47','id': 
'1401305690073586_11252160039985938','created_time': '2020-03-29T13:43:46+0000'}]
```

Desired output will be the following columns as a panda dataframe:

```
message  comments_count  id  created_time
```

Comment: When you say “unlist”, what exactly do you mean?

Comment: Could you provide the desired end result? If you'd like this data in a dataframe a simple `pd.DataFrame(your_list)` would work. Also if this is related to pandas please add the pandas tag to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it’s a list of dictionaries that you want to transform to data-frame you can just do the following:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(l)
# or
df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(l)
```

the output of both use cases is:

```
print(df2)
print(df2.columns)

                  message  ...              created_time
0   Today is a sunny day.  ...  2020-02-29T13:43:46+0000
1  Today is a cloudy day.  ...  2020-03-29T13:43:46+0000

[2 rows x 4 columns]
Index(['message', 'comments_count', 'id', 'created_time'], dtype='object')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to put all of the data into the dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
my_container = [{'message':'Today is a sunny day.','comments_count':'45','id': '1401305690071546_11252160039985938','created_time': '2020-02-29T13:43:46+0000'}, {'message':'Today is a cloudy day.','comments_count':'47','id': '1401305690073586_11252160039985938','created_time': '2020-03-29T13:43:46+0000'}]
df = pd.DataFrame(my_container)
```

If you want an empty dataframe with the correct columns:

```
columns = set()
for d in my_container:
    columns.update(d.keys())
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through the list and find the `type()` of each item

```
dictList = []
for i in myList:
    if type(i) == dict:
        dictList.append(i)
        myList.remove(i)
```